# I'm looking for a monitor tool to test Jitter, ICMP, Traceroute and other network issues

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for a monitor tool to test Jitter, ICMP, Traceroute and other network issues.
it could be an application I run from my company Network in NY and London or a SAAS service that have a service that can do it for me.

I have a problem in my Data Center that I would like to fix. it happens in different times of the day. I want to run the monitor for few days and save the results so we can analyze them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Jitter Measurements**

For precise jitter statistics, you should use a dedicated protocol, such as [Cisco's IP SLA](http://routerjockey.com/2011/05/06/ip-sla-basics/), also see [NIL's wiki](http://wiki.nil.com/IP_SLA_Monitoring) for usage information.  IOS has a UDP responder that is useful as a latency probe.

I would advise against solutions that rely on `ping` to measure jitter, since ping depends on the end host's OS scheduler, which is itself a source of jitter.

Cisco and other targetted solutions take pains to ensure that your stats are as accurate as the platform will allow.

**Traceroute / ICMP logging**

Use MTR, which has a mode to iteratively log the results of a traceroute to a file.  MTR uses ICMP so you can knock out two items at once with it.   The linux one-liner CLI to run `mtr --report -c 5 4.2.2.2` until 11:30 localtime today would be

```
python -c $'import subprocess as sub;from datetime import datetime as dt;dest='4.2.2.2';finish=dt(2012,6,27,11,30);\nwhile (dt.now()<finish): sub.call(["mtr --report -c 5 %s" % dest])' > mtr_logfile.txt
```

If you prefer a standalone script...

```
import subprocess as sub
from datetime import datetime as dt
dest='4.2.2.2'
finish=dt(2012,6,27,11,30)
while (dt.now()<finish):
    sub.call(["mtr --report -c 5 %s" % dest])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using or have access to a linux machine then you may want to have a look at [mtr](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mtr)

> mtr combines the functionality of the traceroute and ping programs in a single network diagnostic tool.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark does perfectly what you describe, and measures jitter for RTP streams too.
Opmanager monitors ping nicely so you can see jitter too.

Comment: Got a good link to using Wireshark for this?

Comment: is there a company that has such an online  service?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of options. As mentioned wireshark can do this, but only on demand, not constantly. For capturing everything you may have to look at a network management and analysis utility like Snort/Solarwinds/Empirix/Agilant which will utilize ethernet taps to suck in everything that crosses the wire (not sure if the first two allow you to do this, the last two do for RTP streams and SIP traffic).